# When using ARC, property values are automatically getting set to nil after being assigned a non-nil value

Tags: objective-c, macos, properties, automatic-ref-counting, null

I'm using ARC when writing a Mac OS X program and I'm running into an interesting problem.  My .h file contains the following lines:

```
@property Profile *profile;

 (void) setProfile:(Profile *) newProfile;

 (Profile *) profile;
```

and the variable profile is declared in the .h as follows:

```
Profile *profile;
```

My .m file has the following implementation of the property:

```
(void) setProfile:(Profile *) newProfile
{
    profile = newProfile;

    if (profile)
    {
        [profileNameTextField setStringValue:profile.name];        
    }
 }

(Profile *) profile
{
    return profile;
}
```

The method setProfile works great, profile gets set to a non-nil value.  The problem is that when some other method in the .m file attempts to access profile, profile is nil.  Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?  I changed

```
@property Profile *profile;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Profile *profile;
```

and still no luck.  Thanks all.

Comment: This won't even compile. Please post the actual code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there's a conflict in the variable name. It's a bad practice to have a property and it's backing ivar have the same name. I'm not 10% sure but your code might be interpreted as having two different 'profile' members.

If in your code you use

```
 x = profile;  // access to the variable
 x = self.profile // access the property
```

Usually the variable backing the property is prefixed with _, so by default the property `profile` is backed with a variable called `_profile`.

You can override the default behaviour by using the `@synthesize` keyword to explicitly set the backing variable.

I would just delete the `profile` variable and leave the property. Also replace `profile` for `_profile` in your getter and setter, and if the compiler still complains, use @synthesize.